# Crystal report displays saved data's length

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am using crystal report 13. I designed a report and tested and previewed and saved it. 
Now i tried printing the same using application.

[image]

The fields gets autosaved with earlier viewed string length, so any valve from DB above this is not displayed.
For example, the field qty is saved with string[7], and so '1.27 UNIT' is displayed as '1.27 UN' alone.

[image]

I Browsed more about it, there is no proper solution.Can anyone help me rectify this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Lee Tickett, Can you help in this issue.?

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like a crystal report issue but assuming all of your quantity will be in 'Units' and no quantity will exceed 7 digits try this formula.

```
split({QTY}," ")[1]  &" "&"UNIT"
```

Comment: it is not with qty alone @cospringsguy. The field cust_name also displays only forst four letters of the customer name. You can see cust_name has string[4].like wise for caddr1,caddr2......etc the string value is zero, and hence no value is displayed even though value exists in DB.

Comment: I think the problem occured, when I designed and tested the crystal report with a sample , which had 4 string valued customer name and no values no caddr1,caddr2.... on saving it and using the same for application, even though different parameter is passed and values are there in db for those fields.